# What to do when we don't see msohtmlclip1 folder in appdata/tmp?

Tags: windows, drupal, drupal-7, ckeditor, admin

In Drupal 7 I am using CKEditor for rich textarea. When I copy paste client mails (Combination of text and images) from Outlook. The images src path is showing like
"C:\Users... user acct\AppData\Local\Temp\msohtmlclip1\01\clip_some.jpg".

Here I encoded images data for some other reasons. It works well in local. In server the path is same but there is no folder "msohtmlclip1" created so not able to access the images.

Please let me know that what can I do to see the "msohtmlclip1" folder. Or Is there any way to change tmp file path in drupal 7 or in CKeditor.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook uses that folder within the current user's AppData directory to store images when you copy & paste a combination of text & image to another application. The img tag will have a src attribute something like `src=file:///c:/users/[username]/AppData/Local/Temp/msohtmlclip1/01/clip_image001.png`. Other applications on the workstation can read that temp file and use the image however they like.

BUT if you're pasting into a web form and submitting that html snippet you're not sending the actual image. When you're running locally you have access to that exact path, but when you're running normally with a web server you're not sending the image so it's not available to the server.

The only way to deal with this is to

- tell users not to paste a combination of text & image from Outlook/Word, or
- have something more clever within the web page that grabs the temporary image and uploads it to the server. You'll probably need some client-side code that can access the filesystem like java or Flash. This is non-trivial, but there is probably some uploader component that will encapsulate this problem for you.

Comment: One more option to the @Rory comment. Create outlook “Signature“ html page with the encoded image (base64) https://www.timeatlas.com/add-outlook-html-signature/